# Subclassing of Widgets which are loaded by uic.loadUi

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I use python 3.6 and pyqt5 and load my Window by `self.ui = uic.loadUi("MainWindow.ui",self)` Mainly there are 2 QtreeViews and one QList Widgets. I've problems with `dropEvent`. I have to separate it to each Widget/model so that I have different 'dropActions'. But everytime I drop I get a call from the `dropEvent` Function of the `self.ui Object` I've tried to change `self.ui.treeView.viewport().installEventFilter(self)` to seperate functions without success. In the docs and in some examples found here and over the net there are the *Widgets subclassed* with the drag and drop functions. But I find no solution for Widgets generated by the uic loader. I've tried to install drag&drop functions inside the models. But no luck at all.

How can I subclass a Widget which is loaded by `uic.loadUi`?

or

How to create rules from where to where drag & drop is allowed ?

Comment: Use [uic.loadUiType](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html#PyQt5.uic.loadUiType) to generate a class that can be sub-classed.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to do your subclassing beforehand.

Create `my_tree_view.py` as follows

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui

class MyTreeView(QtWidgets.QTreeView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

    def dropEvent(self, event: QtGui.QDropEvent):
        print('MyTreeView dropEvent')
        super().dropEvent(event)
```

Then edit your .ui file and add the following near the end after the `</widget>` line.

```
 <customwidgets>
  <customwidget>
   <class>MyTreeView</class>
   <extends>QTreeView</extends>
   <header>my_tree_view</header>
  </customwidget>
 </customwidgets>
```

And then change the following line (further up in your .ui file)
from

```
<widget class="QTreeView" name="treeView">
```

to

```
<widget class="MyTreeView" name="treeView">
```

Comment: Thanks! Very tricky. But not exactly what I am looking for. I've tried like @ekhumoro told, but there I have to change too many things. The purpose is a problem with Drag & Drop features. I found another way, but still not working.